# Convert screen-space vertex to pixel-space point? (DirectX)

Tags: math, directx, pixel, point, vertex

My vertex is already multiplied by the WVP matrix, I need to know where it appears exactly on my screen.

The following formula mostly works, until it says the vertex is on the screen when it shouldn't:

```
float x = vertex.x / vertex.w * screenwidth;
float y = vertex.y / vertex.w * screenheight;
```

Example input/output:
input

```
screenwidth = 684;
screemheight = 425;
vertex = {-8998.621, -6339.585, 111.8489, 186.8493};
```

**good** output

```
x = -32941.28
y = -14419.7656
```

---

input

```
screenwidth = 684;
screenheight = 425;
vertex = {X:-8998,622 Y:-6339,585 Z:-638,1507 W:-563,1493};
```

**bad** output

```
x = 10929.708;
y = 4784.386;
```

The x/y values of the bad output should be negative. A simple w=Abs(w) does not do the trick for different input values...

So: what is the correct way to convert a vertex in screen-space to a point in pixel-space?

Answer (score 0):

I think the catchword you're looking for are normalized device coordinates (NDC).

After transforming your vertex with the WVP and dividing by w, the positions are in NDC. All visible points are lying between -1 and 1 in all axis.

To resolve the screen coordinates from NDC, you have to adjust your formula to

```
float screen_x = (vertex.x / vertex.w + 1) * 0.5 * screenwidth;
float screen_y = (vertex.y / vertex.w + 1) * 0.5 * screenheight;
```

In my own case I additionally had to negate the y-axis to achieve the right coordinate, but I have no source for a reason (maybe someone else have an idea).

Comment: I have seen this example many times on the internet, it seems to be either specific to OpenGL or some different kind of ViewProjectionMatrix, because when I use this code the coordinates appear in the top right of my screen. It also doesn't solve the issue of coordinates that are positive and should be negative. Perhaps it has something to do with perspective/FOV?

Comment: Maybe you need to explain more, what exactly you want to achieve with the specific lines of code. I use this formula to compute screen coordinates from projected coordinates for many purposes and it is working fine. I'm working with with DirectX and HLSL.

Comment: I am trying to make lines in a geometry shader, lines that are the same width regardless of their 3d position. I want the output W value to be 1. Once the lines go behind the near-plane, the screenspace values become incorrect. I can't do culling as that removes the lines while they're still visible.